# Suggest a common database for all the platforms like windows, Mac, IOS, Android etc

Tags: android, ios, windows, macos, platform

Please suggest a common database for all the platforms like windows, Mac, IOS, Android etc...
My aim is to build an application to talk all these mediums in offline and online. To store the data in offline mode, i need to know, how to maintain a storage 
(i.e., common storage so that no need to write a code for each and every medium) in all these mediums.

Please help.

Answer (score 9):

[SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) is the obvious solution. It is natively available in the iOS and Android SDKs, and is also available for Mac and Windows.

Comment: Can you please give any sample application developed with this?

Comment: There are countless thousands of Android and iOS apps using SQLite, but there is this helpful web page listing famous projects which use it: http://www.sqlite.org/famous.html